# How get EF GetValidationErrors to validate decimal magnitude?

Tags: entity-framework, validation, precision

Currently, in EF 6.1.3, if a decimal is declared in Code First with HasPrecision(6,2) and the value is 1234567.0 then GetValidationErrors does not detect any error, and SaveChanges fails.

I don't want to custom validate every entity being written to the database and would like to somehow get GetValidationErrors to validate the magnitude of a decimal about to be written to the database that has precision declared.

Is this possible? May be I'm missing something...Thx!

Answer (score 0):

- You change your property precision for example in your DbContext like that:

> ```
> modelBuilder.Entity<AnEntity>().Property(e => e.property).HasPrecision(14, 12);
> ```

- You can also disabling the automatic validation on Save and create your custom data annotation for the validation:

> `MyDbContext.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;`

- You can create your custom EF validator as described in my post below:
  [Entity Framework UI Validation using WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451413/entity-framework-ui-validation-using-winforms)

Comment: Thx but neither of these answer my question. Changing the precision is not an option. I don't want to validate each and every decimal, I want EF to validate based on the HasPrecision setting. Likely what I am asking is not possible but EF "should" validate based on precision.

Comment: @Dave maybe you write some code example, this will make it more easy to understand exactly what you need. I think it is possibe with the custom data annotation but show me the code to avoid any misunderstanding and I will update the answer.

Comment: I have dozens of models and many decimal fields that use HasPrecision via the fluent interface to set the SQL precision and scale. I simply want that setting to be used in all cases as part of validation, when adding or updating any model in my DbContext, to check that the magnitude of the decimal does not exceed that precision. Iow, precision (6,2) should only allow numbers between -999999.0 and 999999.0 and nothing smaller or larger.