# Is it possible to use IValidatableObject with Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, validation

I am working on WinForms with EF 6.2.

I am trying to implement custom validation logic for my entities with Entity Framework.

At first, I succeeded to override the `DbEntityValidationResult ValidateEntity` method in my DbContext and it's working fine.

But now I have a lot of entities, it becomes very messy and I would like to implement the custom validation directly in my entities classes.

So I tried to implement the `IValidatableObject` interface.
Here is a simple example of an entity :

```
public class Inspection : IValidatableObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "You must enter a description")]
    [StringLength(maximumLength: 15, ErrorMessage = "The description cannot exceed 15 characters")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime? ActualDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ValidityDate { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (ActualDate > ValidityDate)
        {
            ValidationResult result = new ValidationResult("Actual Date connot be > to ValidityDate");
            yield return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I read a lot of things but cannot figure where do I have to call the `Validate` method of my entities, and what value I have to pass in `ValidationContext` parameter.

Every tutorial I've seen targets MVC scenarios so I wonder if it is possible to use it with Winforms.
I maybe have missed something, or maybe it is not the correct approach for validation in Winforms/EF.

Please can you give me some piece of advice ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Framework UI Validation using WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451413/entity-framework-ui-validation-using-winforms)

Comment: @TnTinMn : Thank you for the link. However it doesn't suit me as I have to perform a complex business logic involving several properties in my class.

Comment: @TnTinMn : Finally I found the the solution thanks to this link by looking other answers. So I answered my own question. Thank you.

Comment: The idea is to never call this Validate method but catch validation errors when saving changes or call `context.GetValidationErrors`. BTW, your question is not winforms-specific.

Comment: @Gert Arnold : Yes. That’s what I was trying to do. But for me, the problem was not to catch errors, but to throw them. Despite the fact I found a solution, this is maybe not the best one. Can you tell me how I can implement validation logic in my class, in order to catch the errors in the context.GetValidationErrors ?

Comment: Then why do you ask *cannot figure where do I have to call the Validate method*? I can't follow you.

Comment: Because before I found the solution by reading again the MSDN microsoft, the code I have posted above didn't raise anything. Without adding the memberNames of the ValidationResult class, context.GetValidationErrors was returning no error. That's why I thought I had to call the Validate method, but no idea how and where to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution (and my error) thanks to the MSDN article :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193959.aspx

When I read it the first time, I missed a part while implementing the interface.
I forgot to define the `memberNames` parameter of the `ValidationResult` class.

So I just changed :

```
ValidationResult result = new ValidationResult("Actual Date connot be > to ValidityDate");
```

to

```
ValidationResult result = new ValidationResult("Actual Date connot be > to ValidityDate",
                          new[] { nameof(ActualDate), nameof(ValidityDate) });
```

And it worked as expected.

I am still wondering what value to pass in `ValidationContext` parameter if the `Validate` method of the interface is called manually, but it is another question.

So to answer my own question : Yes, it is possible to use `IValidatableObject` with Winforms.